# No audio but drivers available

Tags: sound

I am new to Linux and installed Ubuntu 18.04.
There is no sound, but I can see the audio drivers as shown in the screenshot.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a reply to someone else's no audio topic after solving a similar problem with my own copy of Ubuntu 18.04 and I thought that you might benefit from it as well. Take a look at it here and see if it helps you as well. Instead of repeating the content, here is a link to my solution. https://askubuntu.com/a/1030811/824173

Comment: I tried. It's not working. But in the pop-up window, i can see the sound bars moving. Any idea how to resolve this please.