# Sound card shown as Dummy Output in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa

Dummy output is showing in *Settings* -> *Sound* in Ubuntu 18.04.

[image] 
<sup>**Dummy Output**</sup>

I tried:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

It does nothing. I am not sure what else to try.

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available. 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 
Release: 18.04 
Codename: bionic 

$ lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_intel          40960  3
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd                    81920  18 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm

$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
     Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [1462:fa15]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

Tried also:

```
$ pacmd list-cards
0 card(s) available.
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

I will further note: When I use USB sound card it does not work on boot it does not show at all. When I disconnect it and connect it again it starts working. How can I establish which application captures the sound cards?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 HP notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042318/no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04-hp-notebook)

Comment: Solution given in the problem above does not work.

Comment: Also make sure you have linux-modules-extra-X.Y installed, snd-hda-intel.ko is there.

Comment: In my case it was a bad kernel upgrade, more specifcally linux-image-5.4.0-1035-oracle. Changing back to an earlier one worked.

Answer (score 11):

Just wanted to add to this, I followed similar [instructions](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html) to have sound work briefly after a reboot with a dell XPS 13 running Ubuntu cosmic (18.10). Switching between 'auto' and 'generic' didn't change much

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

worked for me.

Comment: Previously I tried this and it did now work. However I tried now and it did. Will see after reboot.

Comment: It only worked this time. After reboot I am back to Dummy Output.

Comment: For me it show that none to reload?

Answer (score 3):

### Dummy Output

I realize this is an older question but following the suggested fixes did not work for me.  I was running 16.04 just fine but did a fresh install of 18.04 and lost audio.  I further upgraded to 18.10 and still did not have audio.

### Profile

After a bit of searching, I found help on this [forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=268499).  When running `pacmd list-cards` I noticed that although it saw my audio card, the *active profile* was *off*.  To fix this, I ran:

```bsh
pacmd set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

As soon as I did this, my Sound Preferences showed *Built-in Audio Analog Stereo* under the output tab instead of *Dummy Output*.

Comment: When I run `pacmd list-cards` I get "0 card(s) available`. X1C 7th gen, Ubuntu 18.04. Lenovo had to screw up the X1C... 6th gen sound and microphone worked fine in Ubuntu, now they're both f***ed.

Answer (score 3):

Some other service might be *capturing* the default *audio output* before pulseaudio is able to reserve it. Leaving only a "Dummy Output" as (useless) fallback.
Check via two commands if there's a discrepancy between what `aplay` and what `pulseaudio` sees:

```
$ aplay -l

$ pacmd list-cards
```

If the second command does not include your analog output, but `aplay` lists it, then something is grabbing the analog outputs, preventing *pulseaudio* from using them. Do you have timidity installed? Try stopping or removing it.

Comment: $ pacmd list-cards [0 card(s) available.] $ aplay -l [aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...] tried to remove timidity no change.

Comment: Having thought through your answer careful I now come to conclusion that the capturing of sound card idea is probably correct just with a different application. When I use USB sound card it does not work on boot it does not show at all. When I disconnect it and connect it again it starts working. How can I establish which application captures the sound cards?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. For me, it seems there are competing generations of how audio is supposed to work: one, a number of apps that respect pulseaudio as universal audio api, allowing multple to connect; and two: apps that follow a (possibly older scheme) where they capture audio devices on a lower level, and unintendly breaking resource sharing. Your example shows: who comes first, wins.

Comment: I had the situation described in this answer, and was able to track down the program which was getting in the way with `sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*` and `sudo fuser -v /dev/dsp` (as described at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#No_cards) @berduchwal

Comment: Dude. 1 week of work, maybe 8 total hours, and this is the answer. The world needs to know.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this as well when I dist-upgraded my custom-built desktop from 16.04.x to 18.04.1 (both LTS). After upgrading, sound didn't work. `lspci` listed the audio device but -- unlike yours -- the system stubbornly refused to load the relevant module. `lshw` showed the device as 'unclaimed'.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
<snip>
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio [8086:a2f0]
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 200 Series PCH HD Audio [1043:8723]
<snip>

$ sudo lshw -c sound
     *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
          description: Audio device
          product: 200 Series PCH HD Audio
          vendor: Intel Corporation
```

I tried a bunch of Ask Ubuntu and web answers (such as [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029502/no-audio-on-ubuntu-18-04) [answers](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html)) but they didn't work for me. Eventually I tried the [Sound Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) on help.ubuntu.com, and **Step 3** of the troubleshooting procedures helped me get back sound. Essentially what I did is ran the following commands and rebooted.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-`uname -r`
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-extra-`uname -r`  
sudo apt-get install oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
```

Now `lspci` shows (and sound works):

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio [8086:a2f0]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 200 Series PCH HD Audio [1043:8723]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did not make any difference. From the list of commands provided only first and last worked (update was automatic).

Answer (score 2):

I have a slightly different variation of the problem.

The commands

```
lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
```

and

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
```

both indicated that I have `snd_hda_intel` on the system, however the audio control has always been **Dummy Output**.

Following [Sound Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) as [mentioned by sigint](https://askubuntu.com/a/1090597/527764), I realized that `oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms` is the only one needed.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
sudo apt-get install oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
```

My hardware:

- MB: ASROCK Z370 Pro4
- i7 8700k

Comment: No help. I tried that but it changed nothing for me.

Comment: @berduchwal this sounds silly, but could it be HW problem? e.g. front panel audio wire or connection? I have done this a few times now and it worked on my ASRock and MSI mobo. What kinds of HW you have?

Comment: @berduchwal OK I think I might have found what might be going on.
I have faced again this issue today, and I was scratching my head thinking about that is going on...
Then I plugged in my headphone and restarted the machine, and all the sudden the headphone option come up.
I think this could be due the timing of sound card initialization or it only initialize once at the beginning. 
I have tested the same theory with the line-in input jack at the back of the machine and same result.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Sound initialisation timing sounds a firm possibility. When I reboot sound is Dummy Output but when I unplug and plug back headphones it changes to proper sound card.

Comment: Thanks for this link! https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting helped me find that `linux-image-virtual` package does not install sound card drivers, but `linux-image-generic` does.

Comment: Worked perfectly on my HP Ubuntu 18.04 after reboot!

Answer (score 2):

This bug happened just a couple of times for me, `killall pulseaudio` worked (I think it automatically restarts).

Answer (score 1):

I tried a bunch of options, including all described here, though the only option that worked for me was appending the line

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

to the end of the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

as well as the line

```
blacklist snd_soc_sk
```

to the end of the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

The lines can be appended to the corresponding files using a text editor (with root privileges) or directly with the commands:

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a
```

and

```
echo "blacklist snd_soc_skl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

[source](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

Running in a terminal `pulseaudio -k` worked in a Dell Precision with Ubuntu 18.04