# volume gone and the system does not wake up

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

Thinkpad x1 carbon 7th gen. Sound gone. Only dummy output available. Soundcard not detected

I have a habit of running `sudo apt-get install dist-upgrade` from time to time and i also update the system whenever system updater prompts me to. After the last update i have my system's volume gone. In fact the soundcard is not getting recognized at all. I have tried to `sudo alsa force-reload`. I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059619/sound-card-shown-as-dummy-output-in-ubuntu-18-04). I have tried everything that comes on first page of google if i type "Ubuntu 18.04 sound gone shows only dummy output."

I have tried uninstalling alsa and pulseaudio

also, when i run sudo pulseaudio -k i get:

`E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such file or directory`

Can somebody guide me to get the sound back?

Comment: I have the exact same problem on Ubuntu 19.10. Not only did sound/mic stop working, but also I cannot reboot/shutdown anymore. It gets stuck at "systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM devices".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 ... Very disturbing . I got my speaker back by doing what was written here https://superuser.com/a/1509313/1151609

but i still have issues with my microphone and with the Bluetooth ...

Those updates are excessively annoying ...

Comment: nothing works but the linked answer. i had tried everything. even google search's second page. NOTHING BUT THIS WORKED

Comment: I am glad it solved your problem. You can also use the previous kernel when you boot (the 5.3.0-40 one). It should work too.