# "Dummy Output" causing no audio in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 for a while and it worked perfectly fine for a long time on the same laptop but the audio suddenly doesn't seem to work. On increasing or decreasing the volume I noticed that I can see "Dummy Output" which wouldn't appear before and it is the only output device which is being shown in my system. I have tried various solutions already which had been suggested online but none seem to work. Can anyone please suggest how to fix this issue.

Comment: Sometimes Dummy Output appears on my system but it is gone after a reboot, or by restarting the GDM.

Comment: @Jos I have rebooted my system a number of times but its still the same for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sound card shown as Dummy Output in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059619/sound-card-shown-as-dummy-output-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @David None of the methods mentioned in the page you gave worked for me. Also on typing **aplay -l** on my terminal, I get the output " no soundcards found..."

Comment: I have tried a lot to things. None of the ways in the existing links are working for me. Can anyone please help. I have gone though all the previous links.

Comment: did it get resolved  ?  i am facing the same issue.