# Ubuntu 22.04 on HP Dragonfly Pro sound not working

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio

I'm hoping someone can help me with my sound issue. I installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop (AMD Ryzen 7736 with Radeon graphics). Sound doesn't seem to work. At first, the settings just showed "Dummy Output" for my Sound Output Device. Trying out the following:

- [Upgrade from 21.04 to 22.04, audio lost (Dummy output only)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407616/upgrade-from-21-04-to-22-04-audio-lost-dummy-output-only?newreg=d895d64329734a29a9c847a2fbddca83)
- [ubuntu 22.04 audio output not working (dummy audio)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406646/ubuntu-22-04-audio-output-not-working-dummy-audio)
- [Ubuntu no audio device in output tab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095934/ubuntu-no-audio-device-in-output-tab/1295323#1295323)

I now see "HDMI/DisplayPort-HD-Audio Generic" as the Output Device. However, the sound still isn't working.

```bash
linh@linh-HP-Dragonfly-Pro-Laptop-PC:~$ sudo inxi -SMA 
System:
  Host: linh-HP-Dragonfly-Pro-Laptop-PC Kernel: 6.5.0-15-generic x86_64
    bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 42.9 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Dragonfly Pro Laptop PC
    v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: CND3173C69
  Mobo: HP model: 8A7F v: 01.57 serial: P1111N2WVHZP8Z UEFI: Insyde v: F.12
    date: 03/24/2023
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    driver: snd_pci_acp6x
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.5.0-15-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

```bash
linh@linh-HP-Dragonfly-Pro-Laptop-PC:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```bash
linh@linh-HP-Dragonfly-Pro-Laptop-PC:~$ sudo dmesg|grep -e 'audio\|snd\|intel' 
[    3.433622] snd_pci_acp6x 0000:61:00.5: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.625101] snd_hda_intel 0000:61:00.1: dmic_detect option is deprecated, pass snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 option instead
[    3.625165] snd_hda_intel 0000:61:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.625310] snd_hda_intel 0000:61:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    3.662892] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: ignore pin 0x7, too many assigned pins
[    3.662907] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: ignore pin 0x9, too many assigned pins
[    3.662909] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for Generic: line_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    3.662912] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.662914] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.662916] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    3.662918] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0x3/0x5
[    3.662919] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    3.789366] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    3.789374] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
```

Of note: the pulseaudio service is dead

```bash
linh@linh-HP-Dragonfly-Pro-Laptop-PC:~$ systemctl --full --all --user status pulseaudio
○ pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ○ pulseaudio.socket
```

Probe of the system is available at: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=f7605bd832

**Any suggestions you have would be greatly appreciated**. Thanks!