# No sound after upgrading from Ubntu 16 to Ubuntu 18

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I tried almost everything on this topic but still, the issue persists. Please help

```
==========
    root@active-HP-Notebook:~# inxi -GAz
    Graphics:  Card: Intel HD Graphics 5500
               Display Server: X.org 1.19.6
               drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
               tty size: 73x36 Advanced Data: N/A for root
    Audio:     Card-1 Intel Broadwell-U Audio Controller
               driver: snd_hda_intel
               Card-2 Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Def. Audio Controller
               driver: snd_hda_intel
               Sound: ALSA v: k4.15.0-66-generic

    ==========

    ==========
    root@active-HP-Notebook:~# aplay -l
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
    No protocol specified
    xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
    card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3227 Analog [ALC3227 Analog]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

    ==========

=============
root@active-HP-Notebook:~# pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process

=============
```

Comment: Did you check the answers posted for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029502/no-audio-on-ubuntu-18-04)?

Comment: And check [this link](https://zillowtech.com/ubuntu-no-sound.html) too