# ubuntu 18.04.3 no sound, sound outputs is shown working

Tags: 18.04, sound

I have ubuntu 18.04, and for a while i have no sound on my speakers/earphones. I tried every solution i could find online(killing alsa and pulseaudio, remove and install, pavucontrol settings, changing alsa config file etc.), nothing has worked so far. Does anyone has another solution to try?
[here is my sound settings:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PUxx.png)

[my alsamixer:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57I1i.png)

my speakers is muted because i muted it manually, while my earphones are plugged in.
Any ideas anyone?

edit: i tried every solution here [No audio on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029502/no-audio-on-ubuntu-18-04). still didnt work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No audio on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029502/no-audio-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @TejasLotlikar no, i tried every solution from there and it still didnt work.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Did you by any chance try un-muting the outputs in alsamixer?