# Sound is not working on dual boot MaBook Pro and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, macbook-pro

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 in my MacBook Pro. It's a dual boot. At first the trackpad/mouse didn't work, but that's fixed now.
Now Ubuntu is totally silent; no sound is coming out. I searched solutions and tried all steps of:

(1) https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-nosound.html.en
(2) https://unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/
(3)https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html
(4)[No audio on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029502/no-audio-on-ubuntu-18-04)

1. AlsaMixer
2. Pavucontrol
3. Pulseaudio
4. I tried to find drivers as well.(I forgot which i  tried to install, but it was  complaining the repository does not have released file). I am sure the driver is of intel.

I spent a lot to fix it, but couldn't fix it yet. Any help would be appreciated. I noticed single bar only while running alsamixer.Other bars are absent.

---

My Mac has following features:

MacBook Pro (13 inch, 2017)

Processor:2.3 GHz Dual-e Intel Core i5

Memory: 8 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3

Graphics: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 1536 MB

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and include the model of MacBook Pro.